# Generalizations of the twin primes conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

This is a  question  about generalizations of the twin primes conjecture.

I would like to know a counterexample, or a proof, for the following couple of related arithmetical sentences. The first is

$(\forall p) Prime(p) \Rightarrow (\exists n)(\exists q)(Prime (q) \wedge (p = 2^n + q))$

More informally, if $p$ is prime, then $p$ can be written as the sum of a smaller prime $q$ and a power of $2$. The second is

$(\forall q) Prime(q) \Rightarrow (\exists n)(\exists p)  (Prime(p) \wedge (p = 2^n + q))$

More informally, if $q$ is prime, then there exists a number $n$  such that the sum  of  $q$  and the  $n$-th power of $2$ is a  prime number.

Comment: Is $n$ allowed to be $0$?

Comment: For the first statement, what if $p=2$?

Comment: And $p=127$ is the first counterexample to the statement you intended.

Comment: $q = 271129$ is a counterexample to the second statement.

Comment: @stevenLandsburg, just out of curiosity how does one prove your statement about 127?

Comment: For OP: Check out this paper of Erdos https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf -- it answers at least the first of your questions, and the second should be similar.

Comment: @Lucia, I'm with Steven here. If one can't write properly in formal language, one should not use it, specially if plain english can make the statement perfectly precise.

Comment: I've cleaned up the formal logic to reflect what I believe was intended, excluding a small counterexample noted by Joel.

Answer (score 6):

This was solved by [Erdos](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf), who introduced the idea of a covering congruence.  Erdos shows that if $n$ is congruent to $1\pmod 2$, $1\pmod 7$, $2\pmod 5$, $8\pmod {17}$, $2^7 \pmod{13}$, $2^{23} \pmod {241}$, then $n$ is not the sum of a prime and a power of $2$.  Now this progression is of the form $a\pmod{2\times 5\times 7\times 13\times 17\times 241}$ with $a$ coprime to the modulus, and therefore by Dirichlet contains infinitely many primes. This shows that there are infinitely many counterexamples to the first statement.  See also [Cohen and Selfridge](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0376583-0/S0025-5718-1975-0376583-0.pdf) which should answer your other question too.